# Github Actions on pull request errors

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I'm not really great at using github the most I do is git push and git pull so I ran into this error and have no idea how to fix it

Here's the error

```
Run FORBIDDEN_FILES=("appsettings.json" "program.cs")
  FORBIDDEN_FILES=("appsettings.json" "program.cs")
  for FILE in "${FORBIDDEN_FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "Checking $FILE"
    if git diff --name-only origin/dev_branch..0a7488a784a893ab515dbd8853a32009d3f0d83d | grep -q "^$FILE$"; then
      echo "Error: You are trying to merge changes to a forbidden file: $FILE"
      exit 1
    fi
  done
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Checking appsettings.json
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/dev_branch..0a7488a784a893ab515dbd8853a32009d3f0d83d': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Checking program.cs
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/dev_branch..0a7488a784a893ab515dbd8853a32009d3f0d83d': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Here's the github action code

```
name: Check Forbidden Files

on: pull_request

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Check for forbidden file changes
      run: |
        FORBIDDEN_FILES=("appsettings.json" "program.cs")
        for FILE in "${FORBIDDEN_FILES[@]}"; do
          echo "Checking $FILE"
          if git diff --name-only origin/${{ github.base_ref }}..${{ github.sha }} | grep -q "^$FILE$";     then
            echo "Error: You are trying to merge changes to a forbidden file: $FILE"
            exit 1
          fi
        done
```

The crazy part is I have another almost identical API with this same github action and it never runs into  this error. So far I've tried orphaning the branch I was merging, even tried orphanining and restoring master. Then I Deleted the entire repository and resubmitted my local files to recreate it. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your checkout step, try `with: fetch-depth: 0`. See `actions/checkout`'s [usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the line where you specify the Git revision range to compare in your GitHub Actions workflow. Instead of using…

```
origin/${{ github.base_ref }}..${{ github.sha }}
```

…you can use this:

```
- name: Check for forbidden file changes
  run: |
    FORBIDDEN_FILES=("appsettings.json" "program.cs")
    for FILE in "${FORBIDDEN_FILES[@]}"; do
      echo "Checking $FILE"
      if git diff --name-only ${{ github.base_ref }}..${{ github.sha }} | grep -q "^$FILE$"; then
       echo "Error: You are trying to merge changes to a forbidden file: $FILE"
       exit 1
      fi
    done
```

Comment: I tried this, this morning and still get the same error

fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..4cad9874d0f18dca82f436b7aec3622b15e6cbfc': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.